# c# convert tiff to pdf using itextsharp or atalosoft

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, tiff

I am doing a POC of either using Itextsharp or Atalosoft to convert multipage tiff images to pdf

I have to convert the tiff images to pdf using memory (i.e streamreader, etc) rather then saved .tif images.

can some one please demonstrate an example of using in memory converting tiff images to pdf using itextsharp and or atalosoft using c#

Comment: Take a look at the official iText documentation, more specifically at the [PagedImages](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-10#402-pagedimages.java) example.